# How can I gradate between two colors using CSS/JS on a range slider?

Tags: javascript, css

As you can see the switch on colors is immediate rather than gradating from red to white to blue. Any suggestions?

```js
function rangeSlider() {

  //get range slider as DOM object
  var rangeSlider = document.getElementById("test1").value;

  //get div "container" as DOM object
  var container1 = document.getElementById("container1");

  if (rangeSlider < 50) {

    $("#container1").css("backgroundColor", "blue");
  } else {

    $("#container1").css("backgroundColor", "red");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container1" onchange="rangeSlider()">
  <form action="#">
    <div class="range-field">
      <input type="range" id="test1" onchange="rangeSlider()" min="0" max="100" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added oninput for live change and changed rangeSlider

```js
function rangeSlider() {

  //get range slider as DOM object
  var rangeSlider = document.getElementById("test1").value;

  //get div "container" as DOM object
  var container1 = document.getElementById("container1");

  if (rangeSlider < 50) {
     var colVal = rangeSlider*255/50;
    $("#container1").css("backgroundColor", "rgb("+colVal+", "+colVal+", 255)");
  } else {
    var colVal = 255 - (rangeSlider-50)*255/50
    $("#container1").css("backgroundColor", "rgb(255, "+colVal+", "+colVal+")");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container1">
  <form action="#">
    <div class="range-field">
      <input type="range" id="test1" onchange="rangeSlider()" oninput="rangeSlider()" min="0" max="100" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is working with RGBA values for your colors and calculating the alpha (opacity).

Example: 0 - 49 is blue-ish, 50 white, 51 - 100 is red-ish.

```js
function rangeSlider() {

  //get range slider as DOM object
  var rangeSlider = document.getElementById("test1").value;

  //get div "container" as DOM object
  var container1 = document.getElementById("container1");

  if (rangeSlider < 50) {

    $("#container1").css("backgroundColor", "rgba(0,0,255," + ( 1 -rangeSlider / 50 ) + ")");
  } else {

    $("#container1").css("backgroundColor", "rgba(255,0,0," + ( rangeSlider - 50 ) / 50 + ")");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container1" onchange="rangeSlider()">
  <form action="#">
    <div class="range-field">
      <input type="range" id="test1" oninput="rangeSlider()" min="0" max="100" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to calculate the value for the red component and the blue component of the background color on the base of the value of the input type range.

```js
let r,b,color;
changeColor()

test1.addEventListener("input", changeColor)

function changeColor(){
  r = 255 * test1.value/100;
  b = 255 * (1 - test1.value/100);
  color = `rgb(${r},0,${b})`;
  container1.style.background = color;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">
  <form action="#">
    <div class="range-field">
      <input type="range" id="test1"  min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using a background image.

```js
function rangeSlider() {
  //get range slider as DOM object
  const rangeSlider = document.getElementById("test1").value;
  //get div "container" as DOM object
  const container1 = document.getElementById("container1");
  const colorChange = 100 - rangeSlider;
  $("#container1").css("background-image", "linear-gradient(to right, blue 0%, blue " + colorChange + "%, red " + colorChange + "%)");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container1" onchange="rangeSlider()">
  <form action="#">
    <div class="range-field">
      <input type="range" id="test1" onchange="rangeSlider()" min="0" max="100" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about **combine between two colors**?

I found a good function from Sass for this https://gist.github.com/jedfoster/7939513

```js
function colorMix (color_1, color_2, weight) {
  var d2h = function(d) {return d.toString(16);}  // convert a decimal value to hex
  var h2d = function(h) {return parseInt(h,16);}  // convert a hex value to decimal 
  weight = (typeof(weight) !== 'undefined') ? weight : 50; // set the weight to 50%, if that argument is omitted
  var color = '#';
  for(var i = 0; i <= 5; i += 2) { // loop through each of the 3 hex pairs—red, green, and blue
    var v1 = h2d(color_1.substr(i, 2)), // extract the current pairs
        v2 = h2d(color_2.substr(i, 2)), // combine the current pairs from each source color, according to the specified weight
        val = d2h(Math.floor(v2 + (v1 - v2) * (weight / 100.0))); 
    while(val.length < 2) { val = '0' + val; } // prepend a '0' if val results in a single digit
    color += val; // concatenate val to our new color string
  }
  return color;
};


function rangeSlider() {
  var weight = document.getElementById('range-mix-color').value;
  var resultColor = colorMix('ff0000', '0000bb', weight); // <-- BOOM!!!
  document.getElementById('container').style.backgroundColor = resultColor;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="range-field">
    <input type="range" id="range-mix-color" onchange="rangeSlider()" min="0" max="100">
  </div>
</div>
```